# log4j2 - unresolved symbol debug

Tags: java, servlets, logging, log4j2

This is using (or rather attempting to use) servlets 2.5 and log4j 2.1

The line logger.debug("test") yields cannot resolve symbol debug.

I am a little bit lost as for the reason why because I've followed all the docs as far as I can tell ?

```
    package myPkg;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.web.WebLoggerContextUtils;

@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {
    final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyResource.class);
    logger.debug("test");

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

I have implemented changes in web.xml as per the docs, relevant extract is as follows :

```
   <!-- log4j-->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- end log4j-->
```

And my pom.xml for log4j looks like

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Compile time errors :

(18,17) java:  expected
(18,18) java: illegal start of type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code "logger.debug("test");" should be inside a method, a constructor or at least a static block, like this:

```
public class A {
    {
        logger.debug("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that seems to have resolved the compile time error, but my log4j isn't logging.  Guess that should probably be a separate question on Stackex though  !